# Assigning the value of selected row to a variable, iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to assign the value of indexpath.row  of the row which is currently selected, to a variable, How to do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where (in what method) are you doing this?

This is pretty typical in my table view controllers for table views that only have one section:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 int row = indexPath.row;

 // code using "row" here
```

}